# React Native Push Notifications not working

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I've been struggling to use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) in one of my projects, I've tried on a clean react native project with no luck. I've been testing on Android. What am I missing? Please help!
Here's the link to my demo: https://github.com/platonish/rn-push-notif-demo

```
react-native: 0.57.5
react-native-push-notification: 3.1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turns out I was missing this from my AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
      android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL NAME"/>
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
      android:value="YOUR NOTIFICATION CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"/>
```

Comment: Hey brother I am facing same problem. Would you tell me if I need to use channel if I am using local notifications only. How would I create a channel?